# Inline editor tinymce

Tags: jquery, tinymce

Is it possible to do [this](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable/wysiwyg/wysiwyg.html) in tinyMCE?

If yes, **How?**

Comment: By "this", do you mean use TinyMCE as an inline rich text editor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution [IPWEditor](http://spacebug.com/IPWEditor_In-Place_WYSIWYG_Editor).

Answer (score 2):

And now you can have inline editing with tinyMCe too http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Inline

Answer (score 1):

It looks like CKEditor's new inline editing plugin can do what you're looking for, only more cleanly.

http://nightly-v4.ckeditor.com/3528/samples/inlineall.html